# Google Assistant for Game

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm interested in using Actions and the Assistant to create dynamic dialog for a video game.

Specifically I would want players to be able to speak (literally) to characters and for the characters responses to be determined by Actions, just like the Assistant.

Is there any version of the Assistant available that can be integrated into a game? As far as I can see they offer a lot of the building block services to developers, through the cloud, but nothing as fully featured as Google Assistant

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cool scenario.  Not something Actions on Google supports directly, but if you want to experiment, you could use the Google Assistant SDK to host the Assistant in your game and respond to queries that are meant for your players.
https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/

Love to see what you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

It pretty much comes down to which Framework you use when building your game. If you use Unity for instance, you can use [API.AI's Unity SDK](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/31498).

There are also a lot of other [SDKs](https://docs.api.ai/docs/sdks) provided. I don't think you really have to include the complete Google Assistant SDK, since you most likely will want to write your own responses (?). Some SDKs have speech recognition included, for others you will need a Speech Recignition framework, for instance [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/).